# Regex to match a string composed of an alphabet letter and a number

Tags: javascript, regex

In other words, I want to match strings like these:

```
l0
k2
b4
```

I tried this: `/\w\d/g` but with undesired results:

[image]

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What *is* the desired result? Is the `v2` followed by a `.` desired, for instance? And the `l1` followed by the `1`? In other words, does it matter that the strings stand or their own?

Comment: Try [`\b[a-zA-Z][0-9]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/IpZ7hV/1)

Comment: I think you want to only match 2 char sequences enclosed with whitespace. Use [`/(?:^|\s)([a-z]\d)(?!\S)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/vMwgBn/1) and grab the contents of Group 2. (In the demo, you will see `[^\S\n]`  instead of `\s` as the input is a multiline string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for alphanumeric string, (i.e., composed of alphabets and numbers), then you can use this regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

However, if you want alphabets followed by numbers, then you can use:

```
[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression matches a word (\w) followed by a digit (\d). If you are looking to match a single letter followed by a number, use [a-zA-Z]\d. In JavaScript written as: /[a-zAZ]\d/

Answer (score 0):

what you want most likely this:

```
\w+\d+
```

because without + or *, you will only get 1 character.... try to use + or * if you desire more than 1 in sequence

Comment: then actually either \w\d or [a-zA-Z][0-9], but which case you dont get what you want?